# Data did not fetch from specified path by using uselocation() in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and try to build a movie project like Netflix. I try passing movie data from MovieList page and use Link component to pass the movie data to another page which is Watch page as below. I provide the pathname which is for Watch page in this page.

```js
 <Link to={{ pathname: "/watch", movie: movie }}>
      <div
        className="listItem"
        style={{ left: isHovered && index * 300 - 40 + index * 6.5 }}
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      >
        {isHovered || <img src={movie?.img} alt="" />}

        {isHovered && (
          <>
            <video src={movie?.trailer} autoPlay={true} muted loop />
            <div className="info">
              <div className="icons">
                <PlayArrow className="icon" />
                <Add className="icon" />
                <ThumbUpAltOutlined className="icon" />
                <ThumbDownAltOutlined className="icon" />
              </div>

              <div className="data">
                <span>{movie?.duration}</span>
                <span className="limit">1h</span>
                <span>{movie?.year}</span>
              </div>

              <div className="desc">{movie?.desc}</div>

              <div className="genre">{movie?.genre}</div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </Link>
```

At the Watch page, I use useLocation() to fetch the data and try console.log(location) to see if its contain the data needed but its only showing the pathname without the object (data).

```js
const Watch = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);

  return (
    <div className="watch">
      <Link to="/">
        <div className="arrow">
          <ArrowBackOutlined />
          Home
        </div>
      </Link>
      <video
        className="video"
        autoPlay
        progress
        controls
        src="./assets/video/trailer.mp4"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here are the result when I console log

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN2xf.jpg)

Did I did not pass the data in the correct way or it has new way to pass the data?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you can pass data the following way:

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: "/watch", state: { movie: movie } }}>
```

since the key and the value of movie are the same this would also work:

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: "/watch", state: { movie} }}>
```

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the state inside your link like this.

```
<Link to="/watch" state={{movie:movie}}>
```

It worked for me.